# how to replicate rows with group by in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe in pandas.

```
 order_id    name     email               date         products     prod_amt     
 123         Neil     neil@gmail.com      2020-02-02   NaN          nan
 123         NaN      NaN                 NaT          ABC          120
 123         NaN      NaN                 NaT          DEF          100
 124         Tom      tom@gmail.com       2020-03-02   NaN          nan
 124         NaN      NaN                 NaT          DRT          150
```

I want to replicate column values of `name, email, date` grouping by `order_id`

My desired dataframe would be

```
 order_id    name     email               date         products     prod_amt     
 123         Neil     neil@gmail.com      2020-02-02   NaN          nan
 123         Neil     neil@gmail.com      2020-02-02   ABC          120
 123         Neil     neil@gmail.com      2020-02-02   DEF          100
 124         Tom      tom@gmail.com       2020-03-02   NaN          nan
 124         Tom      tom@gmail.com       2020-03-02   DRT          150
```

How can I do this in Pandas?

Comment: `df.groupby('order_id').ffill()`?

Comment: @anky But I do not want to replicate `products` and `prod_amt`

Comment: How about : `df.update(df.groupby('order_id').ffill().drop(['products',prod_amt],axis=1))` then `print(df)` ?

Comment: @anky it is creating empty dataframe.

Comment: Its working fine for me, i missed the quoted in my previous comment: `df.update(df.groupby('order_id').ffill().drop(['products','prod_amt'],axis=1))` and then `print(df)` , remember `update` is already an inplace operation hence do not assign it back :)

Comment: @anky Yes, sorry Its working. I was trying to assign it back to other variable. Thank you. Can you post this as answer? so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Comments: You want to group on `order_id` and fill missing values for all columns barring 'products' and 'prod_amt' columns.

You can groupby+ffill based on `order_id` , then drop columns which you dont want to update, and pass this under `df.update`:

```
df.update(df.groupby('order_id').ffill().drop(['products','prod_amt'],axis=1))
```

---

```
   order_id  name           email       date products  prod_amt
0       123  Neil  neil@gmail.com 2020-02-02      NaN       NaN
1       123  Neil  neil@gmail.com 2020-02-02      ABC     120.0
2       123  Neil  neil@gmail.com 2020-02-02      DEF     100.0
3       124   Tom   tom@gmail.com 2020-03-02      NaN       NaN
4       124   Tom   tom@gmail.com 2020-03-02      DRT     150.0
```

Answer (score 0):

If your DataFrame is already ordered by *order_id*, you can just
call *ffill* on specific columns:

```
myColumns = ['name', 'email', 'date']
df.loc[:, myColumns] = df.loc[:, myColumns].ffill()
```

Otherwise you can use grouping, as you wrote.

1. Define the function to be applied to each group:

   ```
    def myFill(grp):
        grp.loc[:, myColumns] = grp.loc[:, myColumns].ffill()
        return grp
   ```
2. Then apply this function to each group:

   ```
    df.groupby('order_id').apply(myFill).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
   ```